# Writing(Updating the values) into registers via modbus in python

Tags: python, sockets, simulator, modbus, rs485

I'm able to read the register value in modbus using `03` as the function code and moreover  I'm also able to re-write the currently existing value with the same value which is inside the register via Modbus protocol, but when I try to modify the contents of the register it raises an error saying `socket.timeout: timed out`. How can I modify the contents of a register via Modbus protocol.

Here is the code.

```
import struct
import binascii
import socket
import time
import sys
class main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server_socket = ''

    def send_packet(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.create_connection(('192.168.1.51', 5050), 0.4)
        message=struct.pack('>BBHHBBBBBBB',14,16,295,3,6,0,1,48,0,56,21) //(slaveid,function_code,register_address,quantity of registers,total bytes, values....)
        message += struct.pack('>H',self.computeCRC(message))   

        message_hex = binascii.b2a_hex(message)
        message_bcd = ''.join('{0:04b}'.format(int(char)) for char in str(int(output_hex, 16)))
        print message_hex
        print message_bcd

        self.server_socket.send(message)

        res = self.server_socket.recv(1024)
        print binascii.b2a_hex(res)

    def computeCRC(self,data):
        result = []
        for byte in range(256):
            crc = 0x0000
            for _ in range(8):
                if (byte ^ crc) & 0x0001:
                    crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001
                else: crc >>= 1
                byte >>= 1
            result.append(crc)

        crc = 0xffff
        for a in data:
            idx = result[(crc ^ ord(a)) & 0xff];
            crc = ((crc >> 8) & 0xff) ^ idx
        swapped = ((crc << 8) & 0xff00) | ((crc >> 8) & 0x00ff)
        return swapped


obj = main()

obj.send_packet()
```

Comment: Are you certain you have the correct slave id and the slave connection is configured to accept connections from your master's ip?

Comment: Yes. It is correct. Since I'm able to read data from the slave,hence the slave connection is configured correctly. Yet, I'm not able to write the data into the slave. Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to write to the Slave with another Master?

Comment: I was initially trying with Ethernet Gateway, now will try with USB-serial gateway. I'll get back to you after trying with it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[PyMdobus](https://code.google.com/p/pymodbus/) will make your life much more easier !

This timeout probably means that your modbus server didn't' answer your query.  This appends generally on bad frame format, size, or CRC error.

Looking at the comment / code, you probably miss-interpret the modbus specification ! Your are using `Modbus over serial line` (which is aimed for RSXX serial lines) with TCP witch is wrong. You should read the document **MODBUS MESSAGING ON TCP/IP IMPLEMENTATION GUIDE** available at modbus.org